# Does a Spider-Man crossover comic exist mirroring this scene from Invincible?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, spider-man, invincible

In Issue 33 of *Invincible* (released 28 June 2006), Mark Grayson is transported to an alternate dimension by Angstrom Levy. Immediately after leaving the portal Mark collides with, what is pretty obviously meant to be Spider-Man and Doc Ock, in an alley.

[image]

A few panels later, Mark leaves the dimension with one of Spider-Man's webs attached to him, and that is (I am pretty sure) the last we ever see of that dimension.

[image]

I have wondered since my first reading of the comic if there was ever a mirrored version of the above scene, but in a Spider-Man comic issue; where Invincible appears and interrupts a fight with Doc Ock.

**Does such a comic exist?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a crossover with ***[Marvel Team-Up Vol. 3 #14](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Team-Up_Vol_3_14)***, where Invincible comes through a portal into the Marvel Universe and helps Spider-Man fight Dr. Octopus, before leaving through another portal.

Both issues were written by Robert Kirkman, the creator of Invincible.

> [image: Marvel Team-Up Vol. 3 #14, page 4.]
>
> [image: Marvel Team-Up Vol. 3 #14, page 21.]
>
> <sub>*Marvel Team-Up Vol. 3 #14* (January, 2006)</sub>

Comment: I find it interesting that they chose not to show Spider-Man or Doc Ock clearly in the Invincible comic as if there was a legal issue with doing so, whereas Invincible was clearly shown and named in the Marvel comic.